# How to dynamically reference to different non-copyable/non-moveable object without using raw pointer?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am catching up c++17/20 recently. A while ago, I read a blog post from modrencpp: [no new new](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/no-new-new). I found out that raw pointer is not recommanded and should be avoid in the future.

**edit**: **add explaination of what I try to accomplish.**

As an exercise, I start to modernize our project's code and replace raw pointer by using `std::unique_ptr` or reference. The process was pretty smooth. Most of the time I only need to replace `*` with a `&`. However, I encounter an issue where the code wants to do the following:

`bigObject` is an object too big to copy or uncopyable. (`bigObject` contains mutex). Even though `bigObject` is an uncopayable object, I can use raw pointer reference to different objects and passing it around functions without triggering copy constructor.

```cpp
bigObject* pickEnv(bigObject* prod, bool use_test_env) {
    bigObject* result = null;

    if (use_test_env) {
        result = new bigObject("test");
        result->init();
    } else {
        result = production_env; 
    }
    return result;
}

bigObject prod_env("production");
bigObject* selected_env = pickEnv(use_test, &prod_env);
```

How can this be accomplished without using raw pointer? I tried a lot of different approaches. Most of the approaches trigger copy constructor.

Here are two examples I have tried.

```cpp
bigObject make_test_env() {
    bigObject test_env("test");
    test_env.init();
    return test_env; // compile error: test_env is non-copyable
}

bigObject prod_env("production");
const auto& selected_env = use_test ? make_test_env() : prod_env; 
//compile error: prod_env in this line of code trigger copy constructor because of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.
```

```cpp
// error: bigObject is non-copyable and non-moveable
std::unique_ptr<bigObject> pickEnv(std::unique_ptr<bigObject> prod, bool use_test) {
    if (use_test) {
        return prod;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<bigObject> test_env = std::make_unique<bigObject>(bigObject("test"));
    return result;
}
```

Is it possilbe to dynamically pick different non-copyable object without using raw pointer? How to do it in a more modern way?

Comment: *"The following can be done by using raw pointer:"* -- could you describe in words what "the following" refers to? Something that would allow this question to be found by the next person with the same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach for how to solve this problem would be to use a smart pointer, like `unique_ptr`, to solve this problem. You can't return by-value, as you have found, and raw pointers don't convey proper ownership.

The approach you attempted with `unique_ptr` is *mostly* correct in terms of what would be ideal -- only you have an issue with your `make_unique` call.

When you write:

```cpp
... test_env = std::make_unique(bigObject("test"))
```

This is calling a copy constructor, which `bigObject` doesn't have. `std::make_unique` just **forwards** all arguments to the underlying type's constructor -- so by passing `bigObject("test")`, it's as though you are constructing `bigObject(bigObject("test"))`. What you should be doing is calling `make_unique<bigObject>("test")` (passing the arguments directly to it):

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<bigObject> pickEnv(std::unique_ptr<bigObject> prod, bool use_test) {
    if (use_test) {
        return prod;
    }
    // This was changed; previously it was 'make_unique<bigObject>(bigObject("test"))`
    auto test_env = std::make_unique<bigObject>("test");
    return test_env;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/rK11Yv9x8)</kbd>